# Why django has to use double underscore when making filter queries?

Tags: django, syntax

So in django we write

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__id=3)
```

Which looks ugly because sometimes there are too many underscores

Entry.objects.filter(blog_something_*underscore*_too_*many*_id=3)

why django can't use syntax like

```
[entry.objects if blog.id=3 ]
```

?

I am not expert on this, but why must double underscore? Could there be a more elegant style in python's grammar to write this?

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with it, but I am curious of any other realistic & clean options. Passing arguments to a python function is a hugely basic part of the language, and the authors leveraged keyword argument names. `fields_and_lookups = kwarg.split('__')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django runs on Python, which sets some basic constraints when it comes to syntax, making the following suggested syntax impossible (Python does not allow much re-definition of basic syntax):

```
[entry.objects if blog.id=3 ]
```

Also, "blog" and "id" are not objects, they refer to names in the database, so addressing these as `blog.id` is also problematic. Unless of course it is entered as a string, which is actually what is being done seeing as keyword arguments are passed as a dictionary objects in Python. It could of course be done in other ways, here is an example of how to use dots as separators:

```
def dotstyle(dict):
    retdict = {}
    for key, value in dict.items():
         retdict[key.replace(".", "__")] = value
    return retdict

Entry.objects.filter(**dotstyle({"blog.id": 3})
```

By incorporating this to the filter function in Django, we could do away with the dotstyle function and the awkward **, but we are still left with the dictionary braces, which is probably why they went with the double underscores instead.