# django SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a syntax error in the following lines of code. I've imported math, but my update function still won't work. Telling me keyword can't be an expression and cites the bottom 3 lines. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, liquorID.BottleSize='750 ML', custom=False).update(StorePrice = liquorID.ShelfPrice)

StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, liquorID.BottleSize='750 ML', custom=False).update(StorePrice = (float(liquorID.OffPremisePrice)) + (float(S750Increase)))

StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, liquorID.BottleSize='750 ML', custom=False).update(StorePrice = (float(liquorID.OffPremisePrice) * (float(S750Increase)/100)) + float(liquorID.OffPremisePrice))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use dot in arguments names so this part `liquorID.BottleSize='750 ML'` causes `SyntaxError`

to use related models inside `filter` use lookups that span relationships

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.

So your statement should looks like this:

```
StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, 
                           liquorID__BottleSize='750 ML',
                           custom=False).update(StorePrice=liquorID__ShelfPrice)
```

Comment: Well that solves one problem, but now I've learned that update() doesn't take JOINs. How would I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be something like this

```
StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, liquorID__BottleSize='750 ML', custom=False).update(StorePrice = liquorID__ShelfPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `liquorID.BottleSize`, it is invalid. You can only use valid variable names.:

```
>>> def func():pass
>>> func(a.x=1)
  File "<ipython-input-22-c75a0f520ac0>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Use `liquorID__BottleSize` instead.

Related: [Why django has to use double underscore when making filter queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481682/why-django-has-to-use-double-underscore-when-making-filter-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the name of your named arguments: you can't use dots in them so python has a problem with your `liquorID.BottleSize` named argument